Agent initialization - Netlogo
In my model I have three groups of agents, however they all always start at the same point, if I wanted a group of the three to start at different coordinates: Coordinate 1; coordinate 2 and coordinate 3. Being the same group, how could it be?
create-aves3 aves.3 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = 68 or pcolor = 28 ] 
   set xcor (591 + random 5)
    set ycor (342 + random 5)
    set shape "bird side"
    set energy  random-float 1000 
  set color  blue 
    set size 25 ] 


What is de difference between each group of agents? They are different breeds (like aves3) or they have different values for a variable?
